# Changing the size of arrows in a directed graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I change the size of arrows in a directed graph?

By default, the arrows are too big and clutter the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the default `EdgeShapeFunction` (`"Arrow"`) you can specify the arrow sizes using the the `Arrowheads` directive with `EdgeStyle` or `BaseStyle`:

```
Row[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3,  3 -> 1},  ImageSize -> 300,
      EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[#], (* or BaseStyle-> Arrowheads[#] *)
      PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"Arrowheads[ ", ToString@#, " ]"}], 16, "Panel" ]] & /@ 
      {.1, .05, .03}]
```

[image]

If you use one of built-in edge shapes using the `EdgeShapeFunction` option, you can set the arrow sizes using the suboption `"ArrowSize"`

```
Row[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3,  3 -> 1},  ImageSize -> 300, 
     EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> #], 
     PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"ArrowSize -> ", ToString@#}], 16, "Panel" ]] & /@
     {.1, .05, .03}]
```

[image]

Note: Somehow, the latter approach does not work for `"Arrow"` in version 9.0.1.0.